# $\sigma$-finite measure equivalent definition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, and suppose that exists $f: X \to [0,\infty)$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, and $\int_X f d\mu < \infty$.
Prove that  $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

I've succesfully proved the reserve implication, but I'm struggling on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n$, set $S_{n}:=\{x\in X: f(x)>n^{-1}\}$, then $n^{-1}\mu(S_{n})\leq \displaystyle\int fd\mu<\infty$, so $\mu(S_{n})<\infty$. Now $X=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}S_{n}$.

Comment: Thought was harder, thanks for the clear answer